# Change the last row value within a macro

Tags: excel, vba

I'm sure this will be a quick one for someone. I've found some VBA code that does what I want, I just want it to reference the last row as the last row in column A rather than whatever column it is looking at at that time.

Below is the original code.

```
Private Sub CopyHeaders()
Dim header As Range, headers As Range
Set headers = Worksheets("FPS").Range("A1:BK1") '

For Each header In headers
    If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
        Range(header.Offset(1, 0), header.End(xldown)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("TempTable").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

And this was my attempt.

```
Private Sub CopyHeaders()
Dim header As Range, headers As Range
Dim LastRow As Long
Set headers = Worksheets("FPS").Range("A1:BK1") '

rowlast = Worksheets("FPS").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).Row

For Each header In headers
    If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
        With Worksheets("FPS")
            .Range(.Cells(header.Row + 1, header.Column), .Cells(rowlast, headercolumn)).Copy Destination:=Worksheets("TempTable").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub

Function GetHeaderColumn(header As String) As Integer
    Dim headers As Range
    Set headers = Worksheets("TempTable").Range("A1:Y1")
    GetHeaderColumn = IIf(IsNumeric(Application.Match(header, headers, 0)), Application.Match(header, headers, 0), 0)
End Function
```

I feel like I've got the right idea but just don't know how to implement it. Any help and an explanation would be much appreciated as I am very keen to learn.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Declare all variables.

Don't set a Long.

Assign the worksheet to ALL Range objects.

```
Private Sub CopyHeaders()
Dim header As Range, headers As Range
Dim rowlast As Long
Set headers = Worksheets("FPS").Range("A1:BK1") '

rowlast = Worksheets("FPS").Cells(Rows.Count, "A").End(xlUp).row

For Each header In headers
    If GetHeaderColumn(header.Value) > 0 Then
        With Worksheets("FPS")
            .Range(.Cells(header.row + 1, header.Column), .Cells(rowlast, headercolumn)).Copy _
                Destination:=Worksheets("TempTable").Cells(2, GetHeaderColumn(header.Value))
        End With
    End If
Next
End Sub
```

Comment: Hi Scott, thanks for the quick response. But I'm still getting a Run-time error 424, on the rowlast line. Is there something else I need to be doing? I'm still very new to VBA so not sure what to do. thanks again

Comment: Hey Scott, thanks but now I'm getting a Run-time error 1004 on the line 'Destination' line within the With function.

Comment: `GetHeaderColumn(header.Value)` is pointing to a function.  so without seeing that function I can't give you a definitive answer as to why.  You can try to put it all on one line removing the `_` at the end of the copy line.

Comment: Hi Scott, I've added the function as well

Comment: Do not add it to my answer.  Add it to your original question

Comment: Apologies Scott, I have changed your answer back to what you put and have added the function to my first post

Comment: your function will return 0 if your value is not found in the sheet headers.  When the code stops you need to check if that is returning 0.  That would be the reason for your error.

Comment: But the original is bringing back data, however in some columns it doesnt bring it all due to gaps within the table. But with the use of the corrections it is returning anything but the error.

Comment: I am just asking for you to tell me the value of  `GetHeaderColumn(header.Value)` when it crashes.  When it crashed put `? GetHeaderColumn(header.Value)` in the immediate window.  And tell me what it says.  Also what is `? header.value` at that time.  And `? header.address`